# Variable updating outside of list, but not inside

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

First of all, here is my code:

```
A = "A"
B = "B"
C = "C"
D = "D"
E = "E"

aN = 1
bN = 2
cN = 3
dN = 4
eN = 5

aP = 0
bP = 0
cP = 0
dP = 0
eP = 0

tempList = [ [A, aN], [B, bN] , [C, cN] , [D, dN] , [E, eN] ]
total = [ [A, aP], [B, bP] , [C, cP] , [D, dP] , [E, eP] ]

x = 0
for y in tempList:
    if tempList[x][1] == aN or tempList[x][1] == bN:
        aP = aP + 1
        x = x + 1
        print("yes")
        print(aP)
        print(total)
```

This is what is outputted:

```
yes
1
[['A', 0], ['B', 0], ['C', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0]]
yes
2
[['A', 0], ['B', 0], ['C', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0]]
```

Whenever total is printed, why is aP being returned as 0, whereas in the line before it was returned as 1 or 2?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: Because integers are *immutable*, and `aP` is unrelated to the value referenced by the list after the first `aP = aP + 1`. Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: this is all name binding in python. you're not updating `aP`, you're rebinding `aP` to a new value, but that doesn't change the value in the list.

Comment: Anand, my expected output would be [["A", 1]] etc etc. Jon, thanks for the link. I will give it a read :). Acushner, what is my best option do you think?

Comment: The thing which I am really trying to do is give each of aP, bP etc. a value based on aN, bN etc. So, if aN is 5, aP would be aP + 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the order with which you have assigned the variables. Previously, you have said:

```
total = [ [A, aP], [B, bP] , [C, cP] , [D, dP] , [E, eP] ]
```

And when you assigned this variable, the values of `aP, bP, cP, dP` and `eP` were all 0. This gives the result:

```
[['A', 0], ['B', 0], ['C', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0]]
```

Which is what you're seeing when you print in your loop.

Now later you're changing the value of `aP`. However, this doesn't change the value of `aP` in your `total` variable, because you have already assigned it! The value of total will always be:

```
[['A', 0], ['B', 0], ['C', 0], ['D', 0], ['E', 0]]
```

Until you actually go in and change your `total` variable.

Try replacing the last lines of your loop with:

```
print("yes")
print(aP)
total = [ [A, aP], [B, bP] , [C, cP] , [D, dP] , [E, eP] ]
print(total)
```

And see if you get your desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! Now I just need to work out how I incorporate it into my main body of code :P

Comment: Was going to, but I still gotta wait 3 minutes :P

Comment: Accepted it now. Any chance you would know how I could do the following: (Copy pasted from my previous comment)  
The thing which I am really trying to do is give each of aP, bP etc. a value based on aN, bN etc. So, if aN is 5, aP would be aP + 5 @JCollerton

Comment: I'm at work at the minute, give me an hour or so and I'll help :).

Comment: Sure thing, I think I might have worked it out but help is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Python copies by *value*, not by reference. That means, when you wrote

```
tempList = [ [A, aN], [B, bN] , [C, cN] , [D, dN] , [E, eN] ]  
total = [ [A, aP], [B, bP] , [C, cP] , [D, dP] , [E, eP] ]
```

you were telling Python "put the value of A into total[0][0], and the value of aP into total [0][1], and..." etc, not "treat total[0][0] as a reference to A, and update A when I write to total[0][0] (and total[0][0] when I write to A, too!), and treat total[0][1] as a reference to Ap..." etc.

Python doesn't really do this. There are ways around it, by creating a custom class or by (ab)using a sequence object to be a variable, like so:

```
>>> x = [1234]
>>> y = x
>>> print "y = " + str(y)
y = [1234]
```

What you've done here is say, "Create a list. When I say 'x', refer to that list." Then, you say, "When I say 'y', refer to this list" and then you point y at the same list as you pointed x at. Note that you did **not** point y at x, you pointed y at the same object in memory that x is pointing at (a list object). Now, you can fiddle with the values in the list by referring to them with either variable name:

```
>>> x[0] = 4321
>>> print "y = " + str(y)
y = [4321]
```

Again, y and x are referring to a common object, a list. I can "retarget" x to another list, and break any association x has with y:

```
>>> x = [5555]
>>> print "x = " + str(x)
x = [5555]
>>> print "y = " + str(y)
y = [4321]
```

Now, there are *two* lists in memory, and x is referring to one of them and y to the other. x and y have *no* relationship to one another.